# Auto Layouting Notes and Markers on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, screenshot

I would like to create screenshots automatically from a browser window and annotate some elements on the website.

I am having in mind to write something like this: (pseudo code)

- Place note right of element "#login": "This is the login button"

And the note should be added.

I obviously have to do this directly inside of CSS and/or Javascript because after taking the screenshot the element information would be lost.

What are possible approaches on this?

I am interested in

- Relative positioning of notes, arrows and such next to certain HTML elements
- Auto Positioning of boxes to avoid overlaps
- and anything else which could be useful in this case.

*I post one possible draft solution and hope for alternative and better ones*

I am also interested in already existing modules (jQuery or others) to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning relative positioning:

We want to add a note right to the element "#login":

- Insert a new element, with absolute positioning, as a child of the `<body`> node.
- Obtain the absolute position of the element by iterating from the element back to the `<body>` and adding up the relative positions. (`jQuery's position() would help`)
- Set left/top for the note-element to the calculated absolute position of `#login` plus it's current width

Not answered: Auto positioning